# Ad a parameter to the url - different depending on existing parameters.

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to add a parameter to an url - but have some problem.

for most my urls looks like this:

```
/products/Cables/Network-CAT-cables
```

I then have three buttons that add a parameter to the end of the url - each of the button replaces the last added parameter. It works like this:

```
Click 1: /products/Cables/Network-CAT-cables?param=list
Click 2: /products/Cables/Network-CAT-cables?param=grid
Click 2: /products/Cables/Network-CAT-cables?param=compactlist
```

And i can alternate as i want - these control different layouts of my products. I also have written a filter that when used ads a parameter after my already added parameter, and the script make sure that when I change layout the filter parameter is still after my layout parameter, like this:

```
/products/Cables/Network-CAT-cables?param=list&fss=Cat5-
```

The problem I have is that the system I use have a built in filter - and if that get used my script for adding a parameter doesn't work.

The url would then look like this:

```
/products/Cables/Network-CAT-cables?searchtrack=Parameter+search&amp;sps=d211av450240_2.0d&amp;cat1id=11&amp;cat2id=923&amp;pricesort=false&amp;instock=true
```

I then need the script on my button to add the layout parameter at the end if the url regarldess so it looks like this:

```
/products/Cables/Network-CAT-cables?searchtrack=Parameter+search&amp;sps=d211av450240_2.0d&amp;cat1id=11&amp;cat2id=923&amp;pricesort=false&amp;instock=true&param=list
```

Script I use (with three different classes for my three buttons)

```
$('.click5').on('click', function() {
console.log("Clicked");
var baseUrl = window.location.href.split("?")[0];
var fss = getParametersByName("fss");
var params = getParametersByName("param");
if(params == "grid") param = "grid"; else param = "grid";
var newUrl = baseUrl+"?param="+param;
if((fss).length>0) newUrl = newUrl+"&fss="+fss;
window.location.href=newUrl;
function getParametersByName(name) { name = name.replace(/[[]/, "\    [").replace(/[]]/, "\]"); var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"), results = regex.exec(location.search); return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " ")); } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The steps could be:

1.first parse the URL and copy all parameters except `param` and `fss` to the new URL

2.then append param and fss at the end of the new URL.

```
$('.click5').on('click', function() {
    console.log("Clicked");

    var urlParts = window.location.href.split("?");
    var baseUrl = urlParts[0];
    var parameters = urlParts[1].split("&");
    var newUrl = baseUrl + '?';

    // 1. step - copy all parameters except param and fss
    var i = 0;
    while (i < parameters.length) {
        var kvp = parameters[i];
        var arr = kvp.split("=");

        var name = arr[0];
        var value = arr[1];

        if (name != 'param' && name != 'fss') {
            newUrl = newUrl.appendUrlParam(kvp);
        }
        i++;
    }

    // 2. step - append the param and fss to newUrl
});

String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
};

String.prototype.appendUrlParam = function(kvp) {
    if (this.endsWith("?") || this.endsWith("&")) {
        return this + kvp;
    }
    else if (this.indexOf("?") > 0) {
        return this + "&" + kvp;
    }
    else {
        return this + "?" + kvp;
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi and thanks! im getting this error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list with this script

Comment: Doesn't seems to work - it registers the click bot nothing happends.